# SQL statement to return number based on previous entries AND grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server

for a given table with userid1, userid2, clicktime

I would like to return the number of entries when at a previous time we had an entry with userid1=userid2 and vice versa in other words. The whole thing grouped by month

it should count if

```
userid1      userid2       clicktime
34           67            january
67           34            december
```

The result should be like that :

`Day     Number_of_Matches`

12/22/2016 23
12/23/2016 3
12/24/2016 33

Comment: I don't see a count.  Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: 1) thanks for the edit Gordon

in other words  I am trying to count when an user clicks on another user who had clicked on himself before.

a WRONG statement could be something like

SUM(CASE when userid1 IN (select distinct(userid2) from clicks where clicktime... <--- I dont know what to put here lol )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wish to have one row for any user combination and that each row is having 2 different userids:

```
select case 
when userid1>userid2 then userid1
when userid1<userid2 then userid2 end as userid1, 
case 
when userid1<userid2 then userid1
when userid1>userid2 then userid2 end as userid2, 
clicktime, count(*) from table
group by 1,2,3
```

If you wish to have the 2 combinations it is simply:

```
select 
    userid1,userid2,clicktime, count(*)
    from table
    group by 1,2,3
```

I was assuming that clicktime is a unique month

Comment: Hmmm thank you so much for your contribution! But the query is wrong (even the syntax is very far from a working case statement)

Comment: What is the error code you are receiving? which db are you using? can you supply an example of the desired results?

Comment: I have edited myquestion to show the expected resut thanks again

Comment: I guess, you meant `clicktime = count(*)`

Comment: hmm ? clicktime is a timestamp from the DB, count(*) is part of the query. I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Now I understand the desired results. Can you add another edit to your question? try to supply 3,4 rows of row data with the same fields. for instance, it is not clear how can we switch from month(name/string)  to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to rephrase,

I would like to count all the rows for a given time if at a previous time there were rows with userid1=userid2 and userid2=userid1. In other words, Event x happens when user 1 clicks on user 2 if user 2 has previously clcked on user1. I want to count all event x grouped by time.